# firebase function is not terminating with response.send

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am trying to terminate my functions when some conditions are met. but it looks like function ends but the control is going beyond response.send and failing with exception **"Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"**

Why it is not existing when "res.status(400).send" and what is required to exit?

```
export const getAssessment = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    return cors(req, res, async () => {
        console.log("getAssessment - start");
        const data = req.body;
        const db_fs = admin.firestore();
        const userId = data.userId;
        const bookingDocId = data.bookingDocId;
        console.log("userId " + userId + " bookingDocId " + bookingDocId);

        if (!userId || !bookingDocId) {
            console.error("'userId  or bookingDocId is missing");
            return res.status(400).send({ message: 'userId or bookingDocId is missing' });
        }

        var bookingRef = await db_fs
            .collection("/bookings")
            .doc(bookingDocId)
            .get();

        if (!bookingRef.exists) {
            console.error('No document found with ' + bookingDocId);
            return res.status(400).send({ message: 'No document found with ' + bookingDocId });
        }
        try {
            var reportRef = db_fs.collection("/bookings/" + bookingDocId + "/reports");
            var allReportSnapShot = await reportRef.get();
            let reports = [];
            allReportSnapShot.forEach(report => {
                reports.push(report.data());
            });
            console.log("total reports " + reports.length);
            console.log("getAssessment - end");
            res.status(200).send(reports);
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send({ message: 'failed', data: error });
        }
    })
});
```

Logs:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-getAssessment"
>  getAssessment - start
!  functions: The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.
>  userId 34344 bookingDocId uMMItjSf7h5lAXcHqtL
>  No document found with uMMItjSf7h5lAXcHqtL
i  functions: Finished "us-central1-getAssessment" in ~1s
>  total reports 0
>  getAssessment - end
>  (node:20560) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>      at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
```

Comment: At first glance, there doesn't appear to be anything glaringly obvious that would cause such an error. It's unclear if you are writing your function in TypeScript but if so, remember you need to recompile your functions before running the emulators. The instance executing your Cloud Function isn't immediately terminated when you use `res.end()` or its variants. Instead the state is set to "idle" ready to handle more requests or be terminated if idle for too long. This means functions don't just exit and it's done so instances don't have to be fired up for every single request.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing here - but it looks like if the first conditionals were to be executed then you would send the response and the code would continue to run and send further responses.

Why don't you try set one res at the end, and use your conditionals to build the payload and see if that works?